# Insert in multiple arrays, in hash with key values in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
array1 = [[a,b,c],[1,2,3],[x,y,z]]
array2 = [[1,2,1],[2,2,2],[a,a,a]]
array3 = [[d,d,d], {a=>1,b=>2}]

@keys = key1,key2,key3
```

i need to to show the one single hash in below format

```
  output = {"key1" => [[a,b,c],[1,2,3],[x,y,z]], "key2" => [[1,2,1],[2,2,2],[a,a,a]], "key3" => [[d,d,d], {a=>1,b=>2}] }
```

i am tried to in this code

```
    Hash[@key.zip(array1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple variables can't be manipulated as easily as elements in, say, an array. The easiest way to produce desired output in your case is to just write it out manually.

```
output = {
  key1: array1,
  key2: array2,
  key3: array3,
}
```

If you want to be more dynamic, put your arrays into a usable data structure. *Then* you can use `.zip` or whatever.

```
keys = [:key1, :key2, :key3]
usable_arrays = [array1, array2, array3]

Hash[keys.zip(usable_arrays)]
```

Comment: @najeer: possible, but I won't tell you how, because this is not the way to do it. You must learn to pick and use proper data structures.